# SQL Server query to return if something happened number of times in 30 minutes

Tags: sql-server

I have a user who is doing things for 24hrs, I'd like to see if he's done something 5 times for 30 minutes. So far I am trying with this query, however, never mind what I put in the brackets after `count()` it shows a number that doesn't have any meaning to me ... 5 or 6. And the column name with the date and hour shows an hour that as well seems strange.

```
SELECT 
    User_ID,
    DateAdd(mi, 30, Event_Time),
    count(???) AS NumOFTimes
FROM 
    Table_Name
GROUP BY 
    User_ID, DateAdd(mi, 30, (Event_Time))
HAVING 
    COUNT(User_ID) >= 5
ORDER BY 
    User_ID
```

Resulting output:

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
| user_ID |     (no colum name)     | times |
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
|  295791 | 2017-02-14 19:54:00.000 |     5 |
|  569676 | 2017-02-14 15:34:00.000 |     6 |
|  591081 | 2017-02-14 08:34:00.000 |     6 |
|  803702 | 2017-02-14 12:44:00.000 |     5 |
|  832821 | 2017-02-14 15:23:00.000 |     5 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------+
```

Thanks for the time and support!

Comment: try COUNT(*). Can you post a sqlfiddle or sample of source data?

Comment: Your question is not clear, at least for me. Can you post sample data and expected outcome?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a subquery to add an `end_time` and a self join based on `user_id` and the `event_time` being between the existing `event_time` and calculated `end_time`:

```
select 
    s.user_id
  , s.event_time
  , count(*) as action_count
from (
  select *
    , end_time = dateadd(minute, 30, t1.event_time)
  from t
  ) as s
  inner join t 
    on t.user_id = s.user_id
   and t.event_time >= s.event_time
   and t.event_time <= s.end_time
group by
    s.user_id
  , s.event_time
having count(*) > 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT USER_ID, EVENT_TIME, CT
    FROM TABLE_NAME T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) CT FROM TABLE_NAME T2
        WHERE T.USER_ID = T2.USER_ID
        AND T2.EVENT_TIME BETWEEEN T1.EVENT_TIME AND DATEADD(N, 30, T1.EVENT_TIME)
    ) CTS
    WHERE CTS.CT >= 5
```

This query will, for each row in `TABLE_NAME`, identify the number of records within 30 minutes for the same user.  This approach may not be performant since it requires a separate query for each record, and an index on USER_ID that includes EVENT_TIME may be advisable if the table is large.